# I want to program an ImageView to first rotate slowly and then gradulaly increase the rotation speed

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview

I'm using an ImageView which has a fan image. The layout resource file is this:

**XML LAYOUT CODE:**

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/f786"
android:id="@+id/imggif"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

[image]

In my activity I have defined the ImageView and set the `.animate().rotation()` method. As showed below:

**My MainActivity code:**

```
public class boostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int TIME_OUT = 4000;
private  ImageView iv;
private TextView txv;
private TextView mTextView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.boost_now);

iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imggif);
txv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

iv.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(2500);
```

But the fan image continues to rotate with the same speed. I want it to gradually increase its rotation. I have also tried this:

```
iv.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(3500).rotation(360).setDuration(1000)
```

But it was not useful.

Comment: Please paste your code not only images. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Please see the edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You properly want to use an [animationset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder) which makes it possible to chain animations.

An example:

```
    ObjectAnimator test1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
    test1.setDuration(1000);

    ObjectAnimator test2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
    test1.setDuration(500);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playSequentially(test1, test2);
    set.start();
```